# Can I set Kafka Stream consumer group.id?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm using Kafka Stream library for streaming application.
I wanted to set kafka consumer group id.
Then, I put Kafka stream configuration like below.

```java
    streamsCopnfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "JoinTestApp");
    streamsCopnfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "JonTestClientId1");
    streamsCopnfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 10 * 1000);
    streamsCopnfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstreapServer);
    streamsCopnfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
    streamsCopnfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.Bytes().getClass().getName());
    streamsCopnfiguration.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    streamsCopnfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.consumerPrefix("group.id"), "groupId1");
//    streamsCopnfiguration.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "groupId1");
```

But, my console log kafka consumer configuration not seted group.id.
Just stream application id..

```
2019-03-19 17:17:03,206 [main] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig - ConsumerConfig values: 
auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
auto.offset.reset = earliest
bootstrap.servers = [....]
check.crcs = true
client.dns.lookup = default
client.id = JonTestClientId111-StreamThread-1-consumer
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
enable.auto.commit = false
exclude.internal.topics = true
fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
fetch.min.bytes = 1
group.id = JoinTestApp
heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
interceptor.classes = []
internal.leave.group.on.close = false
```

Can I set kafka stream consumer group.id??

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**No, you can't.** For this purpose in Kafka Streams you need to use `application.id`.

Kafka Streams `application.id` is used at various places to isolate resources used by application from others.

`application.id` is used as Kafka consumer `group.id` for coordination. That's why you can not set `group.id` explicitly.

From [Kafka Streams Official documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams#application-id), `application.id` is also used at following places:

```
 - As the default Kafka consumer and producer client.id prefix
 - As the name of the subdirectory in the state directory (cf. state.dir)
 - As the prefix of internal Kafka topic names
```

Comment: yeah... as i mentioned in answer... You can not explicitly set `group.id` for kafka streams. For Kafka Streams `application.id` will be `group.id`

Comment: but what if two streams consume the same topic? shouldn't the application.id be used as a prefix for group.id and get some streams id appended?